How to turn off suggestions in razor file javascript comments?
In the recent upgrades to VS 2022 (now at 17.9.7)  I am noticing the prompts (I'm not sure of their official name) have changed their operation somewhat and are now popping up in spots that they should not.  I'm not sure exactly what they are called or how to turn them on/off.
The prompts within a comment in javascript are particulary annoying - does anyone know the option to control them (I assume there is one)?
Here is an example of the issue in action:

Another one that is driving me nuts is when the intellicode shows the exact same word that I just typed.  This means I have to press esc before I can move to anywhere else.  Really frustrating as I am editing the code and using the arrows to move to the next spot but have to press esc all the time.
Here's what it looks like just after I changed AC to PEV:

Cheers

If you want to turn off hints in JavaScript comments, you can try the following steps:
1: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > IntelliSense > Default IntelliSense completion mode, change it from "Automatic" to "Tab-only".
2: Additionally, if you want to turn off the automatic pop-up of the member list, you can uncheck the "Auto list members" option. This option is usually found in Text Editor > All Languages > General.

Thanks but #1 was already set to Tab-only and #2 does not seem to make an difference.  I closed and restarted VS but no changes where noticible.  I wish MS would put some explanation on the items in the Option pages.

Actually, #2 did make a difference, I now need to press ctrl+space to bring up the list of memebrs when typing a comment.  It is fairly global though, not sure if it's worth it yet.

Or you can try going to Tools -> Options -> IntelliCode.
Turn off IntelliCode prompts by unchecking all options or selecting options you don't need.
